# Construct two sequences so that $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } \frac{a}{b_{n}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Hey I am supposed to construct two sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} $ such that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } a_n = a,$$
but
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } \frac{a}{b_{n}}.$$

I tried many different combinations with $1/n$, but nothing worked so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

How about $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$? Actually, $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{n}$ works as well...

Answer (score 5):

Take $a_n = e^{-n}$, so that $a=0$, and $b_n = e^{-n}$. The first limit is then $1$, whereas the second is $0$.

Comment: This a nicer example than mine, since both limits are finite.

Comment: I do not see how it is nicer than yours, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can just take $a_n=b_n=1/n$. The left hand side is 1 and the right hand side is zero.